# check if a file exists objective-c

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I used the codes below to check if a file exists

```
bool b=[[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath];
```

The codes worked on IOS.

But When I migrate it to mac os x,

But I found whether the file exists on disk with filePath, 
b always returns 0, which means the file does not exists.

I wonder if there is difference between ios and macosx

Welcome any comment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From docs, I think you're using path with `tilde`

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/fileExistsAtPath:isDirectory:

**path**

> The path of a file or directory. If path begins with a tilde (~), it must first be expanded with stringByExpandingTildeInPath, or this method will return NO.

`tilde` makes path relative to your home directory (such as `/Users/username/`)

you can find out by calling `NSLog(@"%@",filePath);` if filePath is of type NSString

Comment: filePath is from NSOpenPanel,

Comment: @monsabre You shouldn’t accept an answer that does not answer your question, and you shouldn’t post another question just because you didn’t get the answer you were expecting. By accepting an answer, you’re basically telling the community that your problem has been solved. In this case, it clearly wasn’t.